# Swipe between pages button equivalent

Tags: keyboard, mouse, mission-control, multi-touch, gesture

I currently have an external, non-mac, mouse attached to my MacBook Pro. It has extra buttons that you can assign macros to, for instance I assigned the 'move left/right a space' to two of the buttons, which the keys are listed in Mission Control on system preferences. However, I also want to assign the 'Swipe between pages' trackpad function, whereby I swipe left and right, however I cannot find the keys that enable me to do this and hence cannot define a macro for the mouse.

What are the keys-equivalent of swiping between pages?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no universal shortcut. In Safari, two finger swipe functions as Back-/Forward (CMD + ←|→). In Preview, it's Left/Right Page (←|→). Using keyboard shortcuts doesn't give you the nice transitional effects.

You can use BetterTouchTool. It allows you to bind mouse buttons to keyboard shortcuts, either globally or on per-app basis.